# GetJson Using Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, getjson

Hello I am having this issue which I cant seem to figure out were I am getting the latest films from BBC and I am displaying them after that I am fetching each of the films titles and then using the movie db .org api to get the rating of the movie. But the problem here is when I am using the getJson function for the second time as it wont let me input the array as one of the json queries. Here is my code below:

```
$(function(){
var filmnamevar = [];
    $.getJSON('http://www.bbc.co.uk/tv/programmes/formats/films/player/episodes.json?limit=3',function(data){
        console.log('success');
        $.each(data.episodes,function(i,emp){
            $('#epis').append('<div class="episode-l">'+emp.programme+'<div id="epi-img"><img src="http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/192x108/legacy/episode/'+emp.programme.pid+'.jpg"/></div> <div class="ep-title">'+emp.programme.title+'</div><div class="ep-title">'+emp.programme.short_synopsis+'</div></div>');

        console.log(emp);
        filmnamevar.push(emp.programme.title);
        console.log(filmnamevar);
        });

    });

    $.getJSON('http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query='+filmnamevar[whichever number]+'&api_key=81c50c197b83129dd4fc387ca6c8c323&limit=1',function(data2){
        $(data2.results,function(i,rat){
            $('#epis').append('<div class="rating">'+rat.vote_average+'</div>');
        });
    });

    });
```

Comment: What's the error you're seeing? What does "whichever number" refer to? My guess is that's not pulling the index you think it is

Comment: No errors even display in the console for some reason but the 'whichever number' is because the array has 3 entries and I could use any of 0, 1, 2 and it still wouldnt work

Comment: So what's not working? You need to actually tell us what's failing and what errors you're seeing (if any)...

Comment: I have uploaded it to my server @ www.a-collins.com/test

Comment: there are no errors showing it is just not fetching from the getjson but I know for certain that getjson works when you provide it with a single variable instead of an array

Comment: Use a web inspector to view the URL that's being generated and what the server response is. I'm still betting you're not getting what you want from `filmnamevar[whichever number]`

Comment: FYI your current script has `'+filmnamevar+'` but it's an array, you're not getting any values from it. Also, you're getting a 404 error from the getJSON request.

Comment: oh, I see its a variable so I guess I have to separate them into 3 single string variables?

Comment: You're creating an array of titles in `filmnamevar`. Your SO post tells us you're accessing a value with an array key (i.e. `filmnamevar[0]`) but you're not. If you need to run getJSON for each of the values in the array, you'll need to loop it.

Comment: I see thanks a bunch for the help, was stuck for ages.

Comment: Moved my suggestion to an actual answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're appending the titles to an array (`filmnamevar`) but then you're accessing `filmnamevar` directly as if it were a string.

You'll need to loop the array, calling a new getJSON request for each title (unless the movie db API let's you pull many at once):

```
for( var i = 0; i < filmnamevar.length; i++){
  $.getJSON('http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query='+filmnamevar[i]+'&api_key=81c50c197b83129dd4fc387ca6c8c323&limit=1',function(data2){
     $(data2.results,function(i,rat){
       $('#epis').append('<div class="rating">'+rat.vote_average+'</div>');
     });
  });
}
```